# Azure Function Event Hub Output Binding not working when deployed

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am using an Azure Function to get messages from a Rabbit MQ Broker to an Event Hub.

The function works perfect when I run it locally.

Here is the code of the function:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CaseOnline.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Mqtt;
using CaseOnline.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Mqtt.Messaging;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
 
public static class Test
{
 
    [FunctionName("EventHubOutput")]
 
    public static async Task Run(
        [MqttTrigger("topic/#")] IMqttMessage message,
        [EventHub("eventhubname", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")] IAsyncCollector<string> outputEvents,
        ILogger log)
    {
        var body = message.GetMessage();
        var bodyString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
        dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(bodyString);
        obj.Topic = message.Topic;
 
        await outputEvents.AddAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
    }
}
```

When deployed and run in the Azure portal, I get the following error messages:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: EventHubOutput
---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while handling parameter outputEvents after function returned:
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
at (...)
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the bindings incorrectly. Check out [RabbitMQ bindings for Azure Functions overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-rabbitmq#:%7E:text=The%20RabbitMQ%20bindings%20are%20only,the%20RabbitMQ%20API%20with%20Functions.).

*The following example shows a C# function that reads and logs the RabbitMQ message as a RabbitMQ Event:*

```
[FunctionName("RabbitMQTriggerCSharp")]
public static void RabbitMQTrigger_BasicDeliverEventArgs(
    [RabbitMQTrigger("queue", ConnectionStringSetting = "rabbitMQConnectionAppSetting")] BasicDeliverEventArgs args,
    ILogger logger
    )
{
    logger.LogInformation($"C# RabbitMQ queue trigger function processed message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(args.Body)}");
}
```

*The following example shows how to read the message as a POCO:*

```
namespace Company.Function
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public string x { get; set; }
    }

    public class RabbitMQTriggerCSharp{
        [FunctionName("RabbitMQTriggerCSharp")]
        public static void RabbitMQTrigger_BasicDeliverEventArgs(
            [RabbitMQTrigger("queue", ConnectionStringSetting = "rabbitMQConnectionAppSetting")] TestClass pocObj,
            ILogger logger
            )
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"C# RabbitMQ queue trigger function processed message: {pocObj}");
        }
    }
}
```

**I recommend you to check out this complete guide to setup Rabbit MQ Trigger in Azure Functions: [RabbitMQ trigger for Azure Functions overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-rabbitmq-trigger?tabs=csharp)**

Comment: I don't think the issue is related with the broker binding. The CaseOnline.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Mqtt is working fine when it comes to get the message of a given topic. The protocol of the broker is MQTT and this extension seems to work fine. For some reason i can not even put the RabbitMQ trigger that you posted here to work

Comment: And if you check the error message I got an error handling the parameter "outputEvents" that is the specified IAsyncCollector associated to the EventHub

Comment: Can you once try with the MS Docs link I shared above? I think it might be related to binding/compatibility.

Comment: Pls note `The RabbitMQ bindings are only fully supported on Premium and Dedicated plans. Consumption is not supported.`

Comment: Also, can you share a link of the tutorial you followed for this?

Comment: I followed a very popular article by Kees Schollaart and simply added the output binding for the Event Hub. Here is the link:

https://case.schollaart.net/2018/09/22/mqtt-and-azure-functions.html

Comment: I tried with the link you shared above but seems I'm not able to connect to the broker. Since the protocol is MQTT, when I specify the URI as "amqp://user:pass@host:port" I'm not able to connect for some reason

Comment: Sorry, if I was not clear. The above link is for listeners only. You have to call the Azure function link and send MQTT message to it.

Comment: Does the answer help?